# window.resize event in jquery dialog open event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dialog, modal-dialog

Hy,

in my website I use jquery and jquery dialog.
I declare the dialog like

```
$('#' + e).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    ...,
    close: function (type, data) {
        $('#' + e).dialog("destroy");
    },
    open: function (type, data) {
        $(window).resize(function (sender) {
            if ($(window).width() > 850) {
                if ($('#' + e).dialog("isOpen")) {
                    $('#' + e).dialog("close");
                }
            } else {
                $('#' + e).dialog("option", {
                    position: {
                        my: 'center center',
                        at: 'center center',
                        collision: 'fit'
                    },
                    width: $(window).width() * 0.8,
                    height: $(window).height() * 0.8
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

The goal is that the dialog closed if the window width is greater 850px.
The dialog closed fine if the width is reached but the resize event is still running.

How can I use the window.resize event on each dialog to position the dialog and if the dialog is closed than the event must also dispose.

Two days ago I dont have this problem and everything works fine with the same code.

I dont Know what I do wrong, please help me and sry for my bad english.

Best regards
WaZZkeSS

Comment: I haven't used this particular plugin before, but what about instead of trying to talk to the dialog through the settings, you could instead trigger a click on the (x) close button like if(parseInt(window.innerWidth, 10) > 850)) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").trigger("click")

Comment: Hy steven and thx for your reply. I hide the titlebar with $(this).siblings('div.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();

Comment: and it must be closed (also the resize event) autom. if the width is reached.

Answer (score 0):

In your `$(window).resize(function (sender) {` function you need to check is dialog open or not. If it is closed `return false;`

Comment: Hy Alexey and thx for your reply. In above code I check if the Dialog open or not and close the dialog if its open and after the else condition it return false. But the window resize event runs again it occur the error "jquery cannot call methods dialog prior initialization" because the dialog is disposed.

Comment: `dialog("isOpen")` should be available for you.
Do you can to call this `$(window).resize(function (sender) { if($('#' + e).dialog("isOpen")) {return false;} ....`?

Comment: I get the error: 0x800a139e - Laufzeitfehler in JavaScript: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'isOpen'`, because the dialog is destroyed and the resize event still fireing.

Comment: a better way to check if dialog is destroyed is `if ($('#' + e).hasClass('ui-dialog-content'))`. but that not may goal. How can I dispose the window.resize event in dialog open event? Is it posible. In OO programming language it can be deregister. Best regards WaZZ